# Erratum in Boyd and Vanderberghe p. 30?

Tags: geometry, quartics

In Boyd and Vandenberghe's "Convex optimization," page $30$, it's stated that:

> A related family of convex sets is the *ellipsoids*, which have the form
> $$\mathcal{E}=\{x\mid (x-x_c)^TP^{-1}(x-x_c)\leq 1\},$$
> where $P=P^T\succ 0$, i.e., $P$ is symmetric and positive definite.

I understand that $P$ needs to be positive definite, but I fail to see that a symmetric $P$ with $P\succ 0$ is equivalent to positive definiteness. Also no mention is made of $P$ being non-singular, but then $P^{-1}$ is used in the definition. Finally, I believe that requiring the off-diagonal elements of $P$ to be strictly positive prevents the axes of the elipsoid to be parallel to the axes of $\Bbb R^n$, i.e., excludes some relevant ellipsoids from the definition.

The definition of an ellipsoid in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsoid) only calls for $P$ to be symmetric and positive-definite and does not mention $P^{-1}$:

$$\mathcal{E}=\{x\mid (x-x_c)^TP(x-x_c)\leq 1\}.$$

Am I right to understand that the rank of $P$ will be equal to the number of non-zero length axes in the ellipsoid?

(I do not know why the curly braces in the definition of the ellipsoid are not rendered.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you are confused by a notational issue. When Boyd and Vandenberghe introduce the $\succ$ notation at the beginning of section 1.6, they only say that "between symmetric matrices, it represents matrix inequality" and it is easy to misunderstand that as "componentwise inequality". It *does not* mean that; $A \succ 0$ is standard notation for "$A$ is positive definite", and $A \succ B$ is often used to mean $A-B$ is positive definite.

Just to reassure myself that Boyd and Vandenberghe follow this standard convention, I continued to section 2.2.5, where they write that they

> use the notation $\mathbf S^n_{++}$ to denote the set of symmetric positive definite matrices: $$\mathbf S^n_{++} = \{X \in \mathbf S^n : X \succ 0\}.$$

I think this makes it clear that "$P = P^\mathsf T \succ 0$" in the definition of an ellipse simply notation equivalent to saying in words that "$P$ is symmetric and positive definite". (So the follow-up of "i.e., $P$ is symmetric and positive definite" is not meant to hide any *argument*, no matter how obvious - it is simply restating in words what was just said in symbols.)

---

Let me finish by answering the questions not related to notation.

One characterization of (symmetric) positive definite matrices is that all their eigenvalues are positive. In particular, if $P \succ 0$, then $P$ cannot be singular, because then it would have an eigenvalue of $0$, so it makes sense to talk about $P^{-1}$.

From there, if $P\mathbf x = \lambda \mathbf x$, then $P^{-1} \mathbf x = \lambda^{-1}\mathbf x$. Therefore the eigenvalues of $P^{-1}$ are just the reciprocals of the eigenvalues of $P$, and $P \succ 0 \iff P^{-1}\succ 0$.

Boyd and Vandenberghe assume that $P$ is positive definite and use $P^{-1}$ in the definition of the ellipse; meanwhile, Wikipedia assumes that $P$ is positive definite and uses $P$ in the definition of the ellipse. But as we see, if $P$ is positive definite, then so is $P^{-1}$, so the ellipses we get are the same in both cases! It's just that if an ellipse $\mathcal E$ is defined by $P$ from Boyd and Vandenberghe's perspective, then it is defined by $P^{-1}$ from Wikipedia's perspective.

Why would you do this? Well, if *all* you want to do is define an ellipse, then defining it as the set of points $\mathbf x$ with $\mathbf x^{\mathsf T}P \mathbf x \le 1$ is simpler. But if you read on in Wikipedia, you see that with this setup, the lengths of the semi-axes of the ellipse are given by the *reciprocals* of the square roots of the eigenvalues of $P$. If you use $P^{-1}$ in the definition, then the semiaxes are simply given by the square roots of the eigenvalues, which gives us a more intuitive relationship between $P$ and the ellipse.